# dropdown in bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying [this](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) navbar out with a dropdown. When I try to build it into my webservice I don't get the dropdown working. I can click on it but nothing happens there. This is my current setup:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

The navbar looks correct and is styled like in the documentation but there no points that are getting *dropped down*.

Comment: add your code jsfiddle

Comment: @LaljiTadhani sorry, forgot about that. I edited my question now

Comment: Did you link Boobstarp's js file and jquery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add J query & Bootstrap File

Remove this class `collapse`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="width: 60%; margin: 0 auto;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Bar<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Foo</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bar</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Baz</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Navbar
Default navbar
Requires JavaScript plugin

If JavaScript is disabled and the viewport is narrow enough that the navbar collapses, it will be impossible to expand the navbar and view the content within the .navbar-collapse.

The responsive navbar requires the collapse plugin to be included in your version of Bootstrap.

Here is the plugin: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse

From: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Answer (score 1):

Because you are missing responsive dropdown

**HTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 </button>
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/0zj3bc1g/4/)**