# Nav Collapse not working in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, nav

The collapse is not working for the navbar in bootstrap 3 for the following code. I have tried many different things but with limited success.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"  role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">New Blog</a>
   </div>

   <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: Are you including the necessary JS files? Current code will not work without using jQuery and Bootstrap JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dropdown in bootstrap navbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988663/dropdown-in-bootstrap-navbar)

Answer (score 2):

When I add the neccecary JS and CSS files in the snippet, everything seems to work. My guess is that you aren't including the neccesary JS files

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha256-Sk3nkD6mLTMOF0EOpNtsIry+s1CsaqQC1rVLTAy+0yc= sha512-K1qjQ+NcF2TYO/eI3M6v8EiNYZfA95pQumfvcVrTHtwQVDG+aHRqLi/ETn2uB+1JqwYqVG3LIvdm9lj6imS/pQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"  role="navigation">
   <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-ex1-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">New Blog</a>
   </div>

   <div id="navbar-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
     </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going through this collapse-not-working-thing and tried several options. Finally what worked was to load **bootstrap**.min.js **after** **jquery**.min.js.

In my code it would be like:

```
<!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://localhost/fresh/public/assets/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/fresh/public/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>
</body>
</html>
```